# Reading PNG files using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to build a conVNN based on my own image dataset. for that I first   I need to read the files here's what I've done :

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Here generating a tensor of type string that include all the filename with png extention
filename_queue  = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once("test_png/*.png"))
# Initializing a file Reader
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

# Here the file all the files mentioned ie filename queue and
# returns the  the file name and the pixelvalue in form of a tensor !
imageName,imagefile= image_reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_png(imagefile)
tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Coordinate the loading of image files.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    # Get an image tensor and print its value.
    image_tensor = sess.run([image])
    print(image_tensor)

    # Finish off the filename queue coordinator.
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

to make things easy: the `test` folder contains `10 png files` named `1.png 2.png .... 10.png`

when I run the code I get  the following :

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError'>, Attempting to use uninitialized value matching_filenames
     [[Node: matching_filenames/read = Identity[T=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@matching_filenames"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](matching_filenames)]]

Caused by op 'matching_filenames/read', defined at:
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-110a62c88def>", line 3, in <module>
    filename_queue  = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once("test_png/*.png"))
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 68, in match_filenames_once
    collections=[ops.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 197, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 316, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 1338, in identity
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value matching_filenames
     [[Node: matching_filenames/read = Identity[T=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@matching_filenames"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](matching_filenames)]]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1038     try:
-> 1039       return fn(*args)
   1040     except errors.OpError as e:

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1020                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1021                                  status, run_metadata)
   1022 

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2, input_producer)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-110a62c88def> in <module>()
     16 
     17     # Get an image tensor and print its value.
---> 18     image_tensor = sess.run([image])
     19     print(image_tensor)
     20 

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2, input_producer)]]

Caused by op 'ReaderReadV2', defined at:
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-110a62c88def>", line 9, in <module>
    imageName,imagefile= image_reader.read(filename_queue)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\io_ops.py", line 193, in read
    return gen_io_ops._reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 411, in _reader_read_v2
    queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2, input_producer)]]
```

To be honest I have no clew how I'm suppose to solve this ? 
thanks in advance for any hint

**Update**

After  Ujjwal  answer I've the the parameter for `tf.train.string_input_producer` as followed :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
files = os.listdir('test_png')

# Here generating a tensor of type string that include all the filename with png extention
filename_queue  = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)
# Initializing a file Reader
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

# Here the file all the files mentioned ie filename queue and
# returns the  the file name and the pixelvalue in form of a tensor !
imageName,imagefile= image_reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_png(imagefile)
#tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    # Coordinate the loading of image files.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    # Get an image tensor and print its value.
    image_tensor = sess.run([image])
    print(image_tensor)

    # Finish off the filename queue coordinator.
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Now it seem that TF can  find the files but still can't read them, here's  the actual  error message :

```
    [Command: python -u D:\Masterarbeit\Tensorflow\Main\convNN\own_DATA.py]
2017-06-08 15:12:31.845015: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-08 15:12:31.845384: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-08 15:12:31.845662: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-08 15:12:31.845949: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-08 15:12:31.846859: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-08 15:12:31.847174: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-08 15:12:31.847464: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-08 15:12:31.847754: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Can not get size for: 4.png : The system cannot find the file specified.


     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2, input_producer)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Masterarbeit\Tensorflow\Main\convNN\own_DATA.py", line 22, in <module>
    image_tensor = sess.run([image])
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Can not get size for: 4.png : The system cannot find the file specified.


     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2, input_producer)]]

Caused by op 'ReaderReadV2', defined at:
  File "D:\Masterarbeit\Tensorflow\Main\convNN\own_DATA.py", line 12, in <module>
    imageName,imagefile= image_reader.read(filename_queue)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\io_ops.py", line 193, in read
    return gen_io_ops._reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 411, in _reader_read_v2
    queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Can not get size for: 4.png : The system cannot find the file specified.


     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2, input_producer)]]

[Finished in 1.972s]
```

**Update**

Based on Ujjwal  answer is the code that I'm using now, hopefully it may help someone out there :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

# list files name
files = os.listdir("Test_PNG")
files = ["Test_PNG/" + s for s in files]
files = [os.path.abspath(s) for s in files ]


# Here generating a tensor of type string that include all the filename with png extention
filename_queue  = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)
# Initializing a file Reader
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

# Here the file all the files mentioned ie filename queue and
# returns the  the file name and the pixelvalue in form of a tensor !
imageName,imagefile= image_reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_png(imagefile)
#tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    # Coordinate the loading of image files.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    # Get an image tensor and print its value.
    image_tensor = sess.run([image])
    print(image_tensor)

    # Finish off the filename queue coordinator.
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the variables. Try moving `tf.global_variables_initializer()` inside `tf.Session() as sess:` block and run it as `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()`

Comment: thanks for reply, but did you test that ? I changed the code but still get the same error message !?

Comment: do you know how may I figure out if tf can find the images ?

Comment: 1. You should try to provide a full path when using the pattern. 

2. If it cannot find it then it will give you an error saying that the Queue is empty.

3. You can always use `os.path` to get a list of files which concern you and directly use that list as an argument to `string_input_producer()`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help,  I think it solved  a part of the problem !.
I've update the question

Comment: You are making a basic mistake. `os.listdir()` will only give you filenames. It will not give you the complete path. Your error states that the file `4.png` cannot be found.